# ToyVpn and IPv6 messes up IPv4 stack

Tags: android, ipv6

I have been using the ToyVpn sample code and can successfully use it to tunnel IPv4 over IPv4. When I run ToyVpn in that way, the right things happen and all is well. When I tunnel IPv6 over IPv4, however, it seems to mess up my android device's IPv4 stack.

I see IPv6 being tunneled over IPv4 as I would expect, but when I try to run any IPv4 apps (such as ping from a terminal window) I get: "connect: Network is unreachable". It is as if the IPv4 stack has been limited to carrying only the IPv6-in-IPv4 tunnel, and no other IPv4 operations are possible while the tunnel is active. Is this a bug in the way the ToyVpn code is setting up and manipulating the VPN service for IPv6?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, it seems that when an IPv6 is assigned
to the VPN interface the OS disables the IPv4 stack. The fix is
to add the patch below to ToyVpnService.java, which I discovered
by looking at the ics-openvpn-master distribution. Does anyone
know who I should report this to?

Thanks - Fred

```
---
--- ToyVpnService.java.orig 2015-10-13 11:59:32.933593178 -0700
+++ ToyVpnService.java          2015-10-16 13:17:11.579120232 -0700
@@ -23,6 +23,7 @@
 import android.os.Handler;
 import android.os.Message;
 import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor;
+import android.system.OsConstants;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.widget.Toast;

@@ -295,6 +296,11 @@

         // Configure a builder while parsing the parameters.
         Builder builder = new Builder();
+
+   // Copied from ics-openvpn-master
+   builder.allowFamily(OsConstants.AF_INET);
+   builder.allowFamily(OsConstants.AF_INET6);
+
         for (String parameter : parameters.split(" ")) {
             String[] fields = parameter.split(",");
             try {
```